# Filtering Products according to price filter (from to)

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to filter my products according to price, using a form in the view, I'm passing from and to as two separate filters and stuck from there.
here's the code in my Product Model:

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
{
   
    $query->when(
        $filters['from'] ?? false,
        function ($query,$request) {
            $query->whereBetween('price', [$request->from,$request->to]);
        }
    );
}
```

obviously this isn't working and when I dd the request it's giving me the "from" value only.
any ideas??
this is my product controller:

```
public function index()
{        
    $categories = Category::get();
    $products = Product::latest()->filter(request(['category','from','to']))->simplePaginate(5);

    return view('welcome',compact('products','categories',));
}
```

at the moment it's giving me an error of "Trying to get property 'to' of non-object"

Comment: can you show us also the part where you're passing the filters?

Comment: What field type is `price`? Please can you explain what isn't working e.g. it's not filtering, it's not returning anything, it's throwing an error etc.? Please can you also give an example of what that actual values of `from` and `to` are.

Comment: price is a number, for example:
from is 20 and to is 40, I want all products between these two numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the request wrong, Your scope filter function should be like:

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
    {
        $query->when(
            ($filters['from'] && $filters['to']) ?? false,
            function ($query) use ($filters){
                $query->whereBetween('price', [$filters['from'],$filters['to']]);
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend not using the actual `request` as part of the scope as this means that it will always be tied to the request i.e. you wouldn't be able to simply pass the array of the values if you needed to.

Comment: you are right, I just edited the answer

Comment: Cool, cool. So it pretty much just mirrors my answer now :) The check (`($filters['from'] && $filters['to']) ?? false`) will now throw an exception if `from` doesn't exist in the array btw.

Answer (score 1):

At the minute, you're just passing the `from` price to the closure.
When you use [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses), the first argument is passed as the second param of the closure (in this case the `from` price...`false` won't trigger the closure).

You can either add a `use` statement to the closure:

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
{
    $query->when(
        $filters['from'] ?? false,
        function ($query) use ($filters) {
            $query->whereBetween('price', [$filters['from'], $filters['to']]);
        }
    );
}
```

or, if you're using `php >= 7.4`, you can use an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) instead:

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
{
    $query->when(
        $filters['from'] ?? false,
        fn ($query) => $query->whereBetween('price', [$filters['from'], $filters['to']]);
    );
}
```

Furthermore, it would probably make more sense to remove the `when` entirely as you should really be validating the values in your controller.

Comment: yeah that didn't work, it's giving me undefined variable $request

Comment: @OmarMalas Sorry, I'd forgotten to update the last `$request` variable to `$filter`. I've updated my answer now.